# How to return variable in Laravel controller to view properly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

What i want to achieve here is to return a string to my view in laravel, but i what i got is this error

> "Undefined variable: tod (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\opj_view.blade.php)"

and here is my controller look liked :

```
public function index()
{
    $tod = 'test';

    $user = DB::select('select * from tbluser where ID like ?',['%USER%']);

    return view('opj_view',['user '=>$user ],['tod'=>$tod]);
}
```

and here is my view looked like :

```
   <body>
   <?php echo $tod; ?>
      <div>User</div>
      <table border = 1>
         <tr>
            <td>User ID</td>
            <td>Username</td>
         </tr>
         @foreach ($user as $users)
         <tr>
            <td>{{ $users->ID }}</td>
            <td>{{ $users->User_Name }}</td>
         </tr>
         @endforeach
      </table>

   </body>
```

How to print out `$tod` variable properly? Because when I delete my `['tod'=>$tod]` it works, it just string but it said `Undefined Variable`, I am newbie in PHP, is there some way to declare variable? from what i read may way is true.. please need help guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
return view('opj_view',['user '=>$user ],['tod'=>$tod]);
```

To

```
return view('opj_view',['user' => $user, 'tod' => $tod]);
```

You can read the documentation about [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views)

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views) and experiance

```
return view('opj_view',compact('tod,'user'));
```

Or

```
return view('opj_view',['user '=>$user,'tod'=>$tod ]));
```

Or

```
return view('opj_view')->with(['user '=>$user,'tod'=>$tod]);
```

Comment: thank u it's righttt, i can't accept all as answer but i will vote your answer

Answer (score 1):

You're passing two arrays to the view, you just need to have `tod` as an index in the same array:

```
public function index()
{
    $tod = 'test';

    $user = DB::select('select * from tbluser where ID like ?',['%USER%']);

    return view('opj_view',['user '=>$user, 'tod'=>$tod]);
}
```

Comment: thank u it's righttt, i can't accept all as answer but i will vote your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
return view('opj_view')->with('user', 'tod');
```